# Spring Data Redis - Fire & Forget

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, redis, spring-data-redis

I'm looking to implement a fire and forget method that performs a number of writes. I'm using Spring Boot + Spring Data Redis (using the lettuce client) and was wondering if it is possible to obtain an instance of the `RedisStringAsyncConnection` from spring data redis.

According to the [lettuce wiki](https://github.com/lettuce-io/lettuce-core/wiki/Asynchronous-Connections#creating-futures-using-lettuce), it is possible to create a `RedisStringAsyncConnection` and use it to implement a fire and forget style call, e.g.

```
RedisClient client = new RedisClient("localhost", 6379);
RedisStringAsyncConnection<String, String> connection = client.connectAsync();

List<RedisFuture<String>> futures = new ArrayList<RedisFuture<String>>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    futures.add(connection.get("key-" + i, "value-" + i));
}
```

However, I can't seem to be able to create a `RedisStringAsyncConnection` from the spring data provided `RedisTemplate`, nor can I seem to gain access to the underlying `RedisClient` to obtain a `RedisStringAsyncConnection` instance.

Does this mean I have to create my own `RedisClient` bean? In doing this, are there any side affects I should be wary of?

Is there a better way to implement some fore of fire and forget implementation in a non-blocking way?

Any help or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe you could access the underlying `RedisClient` by having it injected in your class (i.e `@Autowired`) ?

Comment: The `RedisClient` is not exposed as a Spring bean by `spring-data-redis`, it is instantiated and passed around. After reviewing the source code I couldn't see a way of obtaining that instantiated instance.